# Vk Streaming API добавления правил PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, vk-streaming-api

Здравствуйте, относительно недвано Вконтакте открыла `Streaming API`, но информации по ней не много 2 статьи на хабре, и документация с примерами использования на Go. С получением правил я разобрался:

```
function GetRules($end_point, $stream_key)
{
    $resp = 'https://'.$end_point.'/rules?key='.$stream_key;
    $resp = file_get_contents($resp);
    $resp = json_decode($resp, true);
    return $resp;
}
```

Но вот с добавлением правил я не понял, вот [документация](https://vk.com/dev/streaming_api_docs), и [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/333942/). Но я не понимаю как именно отправить запрос на добавление именно с  PHP и какая ссылка запроса? Прошу помочь.

Comment: Ты все реализовал?
Собираюсь для фирмы сделать подобное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ждал я ответа, и пока ждал разобрался. Вопрос не стал закрывать т.к. это относительна новая вещь и информации по ней мало. Вот код

```
function SetRules($end_point, $stream_key, $value, $tag)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$end_point.'/rules?key='.$stream_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"rule":{"value":"'.$value.'","tag":"'.$tag.'"}}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $out; //здесь вам вернеться код 200/400 по желанию делайте return для проверки из-вне
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
SetRules('streaming.vk.com', '1234', 'test', '1');
```

---

`streaming.vk.com` — хост для подключения к серверу.

`1234` — ключ доступа. Ключ бессрочный и прекращает действовать только после получения нового ключа.

`test` — Значение для правила.

`1` — Тег.